# Pointers give seg fault

Tags: c++

here's the program

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace std;

    const int widht = 117,height = 26;

    class Paddle
    {
    private:
        int y;
        int originalY;
    public:
        Paddle()
        {        
            y=height/2-2;
            originalY=y;
        }
        inline int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }
        inline void moveUp()
        {
            y--;
        }
        inline void moveDown()
        {
            y++;
        }
        void checkWall()
        {
            if (y<0)
            {
                while (y<0)
                {
                y++;
                }
            }
            else if (y>height)
            {
                while (y>height)
                {
                y--;
                }
            }
        }
        void Reset()
        {
        y=originalY;
        }
    };

    class Ball
    {
    private:
        int x,y;
        int originalX,originalY;
    public:
        Ball()
        {
            x=widht/2;
            y=height/2;
            originalX=x;
            originalY=y;
        }
        inline int getX()
        {
            return x;
        }
        inline int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }
        inline void moveRight()
       {
            x++;
       }
        inline void moveUpRight()
        {
            x++;
            y--;
        }
        inline void moveDownRight()
        {
            x++;
            y++;
        }
        inline void moveLeft()
        {
            x--;
        }
        inline void moveUpLeft()
        {
            y--;
            x--;
        }
        inline void moveDownLeft()
        {
            y++;
            x--;
        }
        inline void Reset()
        {
            x=originalX;
            y=originalY;
       }
    };

    class Manager
    {
    private:
        int score1,score2;
        int columns, rows;
    public:
        int p1y;
        int p2y;
        int ballX,ballY;
        bool gameOver;
        Manager()
        {
            gameOver = false;
        }
        void Draw(Paddle *p1,Paddle *p2,Ball *b)
        {  
            system("cls");
            p1y=p1->getY();
            p2y=p1->getY();
            ballX=b->getX();
            ballY=b->getY();
            for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
            {
                for (int j=0;j<widht;j++)
                {
                    if (i==p1y && j==2)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p1y+1 && j==2)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p1y+2 && j==2)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p1y+3 && j==2)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p1y+4 && j==2)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p2y && j==widht-1)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p2y+1 && j==widht-1)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p2y+2 && j==widht-1)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p2y+3 && j==widht-1)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==p2y+4 && j==widht-1)
                    {
                        cout << "\xDB";
                    }
                    else if (i==ballX && j==ballY)
                    {
                        cout << "O";
                    }
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << p1 -> getY();
        }
        void Input(Paddle *p1,Paddle *p2)
        {
            if (_kbhit())
            {
                switch(_getch())
                {
                    case 'w':
                        p1->moveUp();
                        break;
                    case 's':
                        p1->moveDown();
                        break;
                    case 'i':
                        p2->moveUp();
                        break;
                    case 'k':
                        p2->moveDown();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        void Run(Paddle *p1,Paddle *p2, Ball *b)
        {
            while(!gameOver)
            {
                Draw(p1,p2,b);
                Input(p1,p2);
                Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Paddle *p1;
        Paddle *p2;
        Ball *b;
        Manager *m;
        m->Run(p1,p2,b);
        return 0;
    }
```

I can't understand why when i launch the program it give (with the debugger) segmentation fault.
I think cause are pointers, because before it worked perfectly(but without modifiyng values);
Hae any tips?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page if you've not already done so.  More urgently, though, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is not clear that your code is minimal — it seems quite long.

Comment: Only give that part of code which you think gives error.

Comment: All your pointers in `main()` are uninitialized.  Using any of them is bound to lead to undefined behaviour.  You need to initialize `m` properly — and it is not clear what `p1`, `p2`, and `b` should be initialized to, but they aren't passed by reference, so they're a disaster if the `Run` got called (it doesn't because `m` is also a disaster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned anything to the pointers to the `Paddle`, `Ball` or `Manager` variables in your main method.

By default the won't be initialised and will point somewhere in memory, which may or may not be accessible to your application. When you access them and the memory is inaccessible you get the access violation or segfault you're observing.

There are two approaches you could take. If you change your main as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Paddle p1;
    Paddle p2;
    Ball b;
    Manager m;
    m.Run(&p1,&p2,&b);
    return 0;
}
```

Then an instance of each of the classes will exist on the stack. Since the application exits once `m.Run` returns it's safe to use this approach as the lifetime of the objects is longer than the code called by `Run`.

Alternatively you can allocate them on the heap. In this case you can use:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Paddle>( new Paddle );
    std::unique_ptr<Paddle>( new Paddle );
    std::unique_ptr<Ball>( new Ball );
    std::unique_ptr<Manager>( new Manager );
    m->Run(p1.get(),p2.get(),b.get());
    return 0;
}
```

The `unique_ptr` will hold a pointer to a `Paddle` etc allocated on the heap and will automatically clean it up for you once the `main` method returns.

Comment: I've always wondered why you'd choose a unique_ptr in such case?

Comment: In that exact scenario, I probably wouldn't - the stack allocated objects are simpler and achieve exactly the same effect. I included it to illustrate an alternative with heap allocation. I would use the `unique_ptr` in this context if I was constructing a number of objects that would be passed into the manager and ownership transferred, and wanted to be sure that if setup failed part way through that the objects constructed earlier would be cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

You never allocated any memory for and you never initialized

```
Paddle *p1;
Paddle *p2;
Ball *b;
Manager *m;
```

Using those pointers is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of using pointers you should change all of your objects to regular automatic objects like

```
Paddle p1;
Paddle p2;
Ball b;
Manager m;
```

And then pass them by reference in your functions instead of by pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Manager *m;
    m->Run(p1,p2,b);
```

You can't use the value of a variable until you assign a variable a value. You don't assign `m` a value but then you immediately use it. That can't possibly work right.

The code `Manager *m;` just declares a variable called `m` that is of type `pointer to Manager`. But it doesn't point to anything yet.

The code `m->Run(p1,p2,b);` invokes the `Run` method on the `Manager` that `m` points to. It makes no sense to do this if `m` does not point to an instance of class `Manager`.